# Limits with sine and a fraction

Tags: limits

> $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{2}{x^2-1}{sinx}=?$

**Personal work :**

For sure, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{2}{x^2-1}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{2}{x^2}=0^+$

But what about $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}sinx?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By squeeze theorem

$$0\le\left|\frac{2}{x^2-1}{\sin x}\right|<\frac{2}{x^2-1}\to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

The limit is zero because $sin$  is bounded. $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a} fg=0$ if $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}f=0$ and $g$ is bounded.

Comment: How can I prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}sinx=0$?

Comment: You can't, because that isn't true.  Nor does it need to be: all you need to realize is that $-1\leq\sin x\leq 1$ for all $x$.  Squeeze theorem does the rest.

Comment: This limit does not exist but $|sin(x)|\leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{2\sin x}{x^{2}-1}\right|\leq\dfrac{2}{x^{2}-x^{2}/2}=\dfrac{4}{x^{2}}\leq\dfrac{4}{x}\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
whenever $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Can you show me  the steps you did to arrive to those inequalities?

Comment: First that $|\sin x|\leq 1$. Second is that, for large $x>0$, $x^{2}-x^{2}/2\leq x^{2}-1$, so $1/(x^{2}-1)\leq 1/(x^{2}-x^{2}/2)$. Lastly, $x\leq x^{2}$, so $1/x^{2}\leq 1/x$.